# Canonical way to implement templated virtual functions

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, virtual-functions

In my application I need to abstract a templated algorithm so that it can be chosen at runtime.
I kind of want 'templated virtual functions' (where both the ifce and impl are instantiated at compile time with a list of allowed types) but I understand I can't template virtual functions in C++.
I've had a few ideas along the way and this is the best I've come up with so far -- but I'm really not happy with how complicated this is.
Am I missing something more obvious here?
I need the solution to be fast and also derived from a common base class.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

enum class calc_enum { calc_1, calc_2, calc_3 };

// implementation class
template<typename F, typename T, typename... U> struct algo_impl;

// base class
struct algo_base {};

// interface class
template<typename... U> struct algo_ifce;

template<>
struct algo_ifce<> : algo_base
{
    template<typename F, typename T>
    algo_ifce(std::shared_ptr<algo_impl<F, T>>&& ptr) 
        : ptr_{ std::move(ptr) }
    {}

    template<typename V>
    V calc_ifce(V val) {
        throw std::runtime_error("nope");
    }

    std::shared_ptr<void> ptr_;
};

template<typename U, typename... REST>
struct algo_ifce<U, REST...> : algo_ifce<REST...>
{
    using fn_type = U(*)(void*, U);

    template<typename F, typename T>
    algo_ifce(std::shared_ptr<algo_impl<F, T, U, REST...>>&& ptr_)
        : algo_ifce<REST...>(std::shared_ptr<algo_impl<F, T, REST...>>(std::move(ptr_))), fn_(algo_impl<F, T, U, REST...>::calc_static)
    {}

    template<typename V>
    V calc_ifce(V val) {
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<U, V>) return calc_dispatch(val);
        else return algo_ifce<REST...>::template calc_ifce<V>(val);
    }

    U calc_dispatch(U val) { 
        return fn_(algo_ifce<REST...>::ptr_.get(), val);
    }

    fn_type fn_;
};

template<typename F, typename T>
struct algo_impl<F, T>
{
    algo_impl(T data) 
        : data_{ data }
    {}

    T data_;
};

template<typename F, typename T, typename U, typename... REST>
struct algo_impl<F, T, U, REST...> : algo_impl<F, T, REST...>
{
    algo_impl(T data) 
        : algo_impl<F, T, REST...>{ data }
    {}

    static U calc_static(void* ptr, U val) {
        return static_cast<algo_impl*>(ptr)->calc_algo(val); 
    }

    U calc_algo(U val) {
        return F::template calc<U>(val, algo_impl<F, T, REST...>::data_);
    }
};

// algo types
template<typename T>
struct calc_impl_1
{
    template<typename U> static U calc(U val, T data) {
        std::cout << "algo 1, T:" << typeid(T).name() << ", U:" << typeid(U).name() << std::endl;
        return static_cast<U>(data) + val;
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct calc_impl_2
{
    template<typename U> static U calc(U val, T data) {
        std::cout << "algo 2, T:" << typeid(T).name() << ", U:" << typeid(U).name() << std::endl;
        return static_cast<U>(data) * val;
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct calc_impl_3
{
    template<typename U> static U calc(U val, T data) {
        std::cout << "algo 3, T:" << typeid(T).name() << ", U:" << typeid(U).name() << std::endl;
        return static_cast<U>(data) - val;
    }
};

template<typename T, typename... U>
std::shared_ptr<algo_ifce<U...>> make_algo(calc_enum e, T data)
{
    switch (e) {
    case calc_enum::calc_1: return std::make_shared<algo_ifce<U...>>(std::make_shared<algo_impl<calc_impl_1<T>, T, U...>>(data)); break;
    case calc_enum::calc_2: return std::make_shared<algo_ifce<U...>>(std::make_shared<algo_impl<calc_impl_2<T>, T, U...>>(data)); break;
    case calc_enum::calc_3: return std::make_shared<algo_ifce<U...>>(std::make_shared<algo_impl<calc_impl_3<T>, T, U...>>(data)); break;
    default: throw std::runtime_error("unrecognised algo");
    }
}

template<typename T, typename... U>
struct algo_container
{
    algo_container(calc_enum algo, T data)
        : algo_{ make_algo<T, U...>(algo, data) }
    {}

    template<typename V> V calc(V val) {
        return algo_->template calc_ifce<V>(val);
    }

    std::shared_ptr<algo_ifce<U...>> algo_;
};

template<typename T>
struct my_num
{
    my_num(T t) 
        : t_{ t }
    {}

    operator T() const { return t_; }

    T t_;
};

template<typename T> my_num(T)->my_num<T>;

void test_algo_c()
{
    //               data type        types of calc supported            runtime algo     data
    //             v------------v  v---------------------------v      v---------------v   v--v
    algo_container<double,         double, float, my_num<double> > a1(calc_enum::calc_1,  1.0);
    algo_container<float,          double, float, my_num<double> > a2(calc_enum::calc_2,  1.0f);
    algo_container<my_num<double>, double, float, my_num<double> > a3(calc_enum::calc_3,  1.0);

    a1.calc(2.0f);         // supported                  output: algo 1, T : double, U : float
    a1.calc(3.0);          // supported                  output: algo 1, T : double, U : double
    a1.calc(my_num(-1.0)); // supported                  output: algo 1, T : double, U : struct my_num<double>
    a2.calc(2.0f);         // supported                  output: algo 2, T : float, U : float
    a2.calc(2.0);          // supported                  output: algo 2, T : float, U : double
    a2.calc(my_num(-2.0)); // supported                  output: algo 2, T : float, U : struct my_num<double>
    //a2.calc(5);          // crash, no int version...   output: n/a
    a3.calc(2.0f);         // supported                  output: algo 3, T : struct my_num<double>, U : float
    a3.calc(2.0);          // supported                  output: algo 3, T : struct my_num<double>, U : double
    a3.calc(my_num(1.5));  // supported                  output: algo 3, T : struct my_num<double>, U : struct my_num<double>

}
```

**Update**

I altered the original code to have a stack of recursive interface classes that contain the virtual function and a static dispatch function to select the correct virtual function. Then I have a stack of recursive implementation classes that implement the function. This works really well and only has one virtual function overhead (kind of what I was going for in the beginning). Also now it doesn't compile if the type isn't available (instead of an exception before). I still can't help feeling there's a better way of doing this though...

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

enum class calc_enum { calc_1, calc_2, calc_3 };

// interface class
template<typename... U> struct algo_ifce;

template<>
struct algo_ifce<>
{};

template<typename U, typename... REST>
struct algo_ifce<U, REST...> : algo_ifce<REST...>
{
    template<typename V>
    V calc_ifce(V val) {
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<U, V>) return calc_dispatch(val);
        else return algo_ifce<REST...>::template calc_ifce<V>(val);
    }
    virtual U calc_dispatch(U val) = 0;
};

template<typename F, typename I, typename T, typename... U>
struct algo_impl;

template<typename F, typename I, typename T>
struct algo_impl<F, I, T> : I
{
    algo_impl(T data) : data_{ data } {}
    T data_;
};

template<typename F, typename I, typename T, typename U, typename... REST>
struct algo_impl<F, I, T, U, REST...> : algo_impl<F, I, T, REST...>
{
    algo_impl(T data) : algo_impl<F, I, T, REST...>{ data } {}
    virtual U calc_dispatch(U val) override { return F::template calc<U>(val, algo_impl<F, I, T, REST...>::data_); }
};

// algo types
template<typename T>
struct calc_impl_1
{
    template<typename U> static U calc(U val, T data) {
        std::cout << "algo 1, T:" << typeid(T).name() << ", U:" << typeid(U).name() << std::endl;
        return static_cast<U>(data) + val;
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct calc_impl_2
{
    template<typename U> static U calc(U val, T data) {
        std::cout << "algo 2, T:" << typeid(T).name() << ", U:" << typeid(U).name() << std::endl;
        return static_cast<U>(data) * val;
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct calc_impl_3
{
    template<typename U> static U calc(U val, T data) {
        std::cout << "algo 3, T:" << typeid(T).name() << ", U:" << typeid(U).name() << std::endl;
        return static_cast<U>(data) - val;
    }
};

template<typename T, typename... U>
std::unique_ptr<algo_ifce<U...>> make_algo(calc_enum e, T data)
{
    switch (e) {
    case calc_enum::calc_1: return std::make_unique<algo_impl<calc_impl_1<T>, algo_ifce<U...>, T, U...>>(data); break;
    case calc_enum::calc_2: return std::make_unique<algo_impl<calc_impl_2<T>, algo_ifce<U...>, T, U...>>(data); break;
    case calc_enum::calc_3: return std::make_unique<algo_impl<calc_impl_3<T>, algo_ifce<U...>, T, U...>>(data); break;
    default: throw std::runtime_error("unrecognised algo");
    }
}

template<typename T, typename... U>
struct algo_container
{
    algo_container(calc_enum algo, T data)
        : algo_{ make_algo<T, U...>(algo, data) }
    {}

    template<typename V> V calc(V val) {
        return algo_->template calc_ifce<V>(val);
    }

    std::unique_ptr<algo_ifce<U...>> algo_;
};

template<typename T>
struct my_num
{
    my_num(T t) 
        : t_{ t }
    {}

    operator T() const { return t_; }

    T t_;
};

template<typename T> my_num(T)->my_num<T>;

void test_algo_d()
{
    //               data type        types of calc supported            runtime algo     data
    //             v------------v  v---------------------------v      v---------------v   v--v
    algo_container<double,         double, float, my_num<double> > a1(calc_enum::calc_1,  1.0);
    algo_container<float,          double, float, my_num<double> > a2(calc_enum::calc_2,  1.0f);
    algo_container<my_num<double>, double, float, my_num<double> > a3(calc_enum::calc_3,  1.0);

    a1.calc(2.0f);         // supported                  output: algo 1, T : double, U : float
    a1.calc(3.0);          // supported                  output: algo 1, T : double, U : double
    a1.calc(my_num(-1.0)); // supported                  output: algo 1, T : double, U : struct my_num<double>
    a2.calc(2.0f);         // supported                  output: algo 2, T : float, U : float
    a2.calc(2.0);          // supported                  output: algo 2, T : float, U : double
    a2.calc(my_num(-2.0)); // supported                  output: algo 2, T : float, U : struct my_num<double>
    //a2.calc(5);          // doesn't compile as wanted...
    a3.calc(2.0f);         // supported                  output: algo 3, T : struct my_num<double>, U :float
    a3.calc(2.0);          // supported                  output: algo 3, T : struct my_num<double>, U :double
    a3.calc(my_num(1.5));  // supported                  output: algo 3, T : struct my_num<double>, U :struct my_num<double>

}
```

Comment: Is it meant to be used  polymorphically? Your algo_base is empty clas..

Comment: No, good point, I don't think I need the common base. My original solution used a dynamic_cast from a polymorphic base.

Comment: ifce ? imho taking the few secs it takes to write a full wrd inst of cryptic abrvs is a matter of pltness, just saying ;)

Comment: @squashed then you might go with a mixture of CRTP and dispatcher? At least that one would look more canonycal. And would gracefully avoid crashes

Comment: Thanks -- I didn't investigate CRTP initially because I definitely need to erase the algo at compile time -- I presume this is what you mean by dispatcher...? I'll give it a go...